# save the changes using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to do two things: 1) Assign a variable every time. 2) Save the changes within the file every time I use it. For example;
cat file.i

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 11 12
```

now I want to increase every second line, starting from nth line, in the 2nd column by 9.88% to get this file:

```
1  2  3
4  5.494 6
7  8  9
10 11.0868 12
```

I used the following script but the issue is that I have to change the 9.88% every time I get different increment, I would like to have one variable that I change and it can go for all of them and I want the change to be saved in the original file.

```
awk  'NR==1 {print $2*1.0988}  NR==2 {print $2*1.0988}' file.i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** As OP changed requirement again a bit so putting new code here.

```
awk -v line="124" -v diff="6" '(FNR==line || FNR==(line+diff)) && (FNR>=124 && FNR<=160){$2=(($2*9.88)/100)+$2;diff+=6} 1'  Input_file
```

---

***EDIT:***  As per OP, OP only want to grab lines between 124 to 160 and who are fully divided by 2.

```
awk 'FNR%2==0 && (FNR>=124 && FNR<=160){$2=(($2*9.88)/100)+$2} 1'
```

---

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR%2==0{$2=(($2*9.88)/100)+$2} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above code too.

***Explanation of above code:***

```
awk '
FNR%2==0{               ##Checking condition if line number is divided by 2 is fully divided by 2 if this is TRUE then do following.
  $2=(($2*9.88)/100)+$2}##Re-creating $2 here by doing multiplication with 9.88 nd dividing it by 100 to get its 9.88% and adding itself to it.
1                       ##Mentioning 1 here, awk works on method of condition then action, so making condition TRUE here and not mentioning any action so by default print of current will happen.
' Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :).   If this file has a 1000 lines and I want this script to work only between line 124 to 160 only in column 2, how can I change it? for example starts from 124,126,128, ....,160 then stop.

Comment: @Mohd, please check my update now it will look for lines between 120 to 164 and only those which are even(divided by 2) not all, let me know?

Comment: works perfect and  I am sorry for not clarifying this properly. Now it seems only work for second line. If I want to change that for example to let it start from line 124 and goes by 6th lines, such as 124,130,136,...160.

Comment: @Mohd, please check my EDIT2 now and let me know?